# Selenium python drop down menu select

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I need to select an element from a drop-down menu.

The dropdown menu has two value and I need to select the second "sponsor.com"

```
<select tabindex="1" name="userDomain" onchange="javascript:doWFAction('ReloadUser');">
  <optgroup label="Selected">
    <option value="0" selected=""></option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other">
    <option value="261">sponsor.com</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

What I have tried but doesnt work (I am a beginner, actually my first project)

---

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='261']").click()
```

---

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='userDomain']/option[text()='Other']").click()
```

---

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('userDomain'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Other')
select.select_by_value('261').click()
```

---

if I do this command

```
driver.find_element_by_name('userDomain').click()
```

I can click on the drop-down menu but don't know how to select sponsor.com

Comment: the code where I am Searching
<select tabindex="1" name="userDomain" onchange="javascript:doWFAction('ReloadUser');">
  <optgroup label="Selected">
    <option value="0" selected=""></option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other">
    <option value="261">sponsor.com</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

Comment: Are you sure that the select list is open and visible? Usually, you need to click on the select before clicking on the options. (If that's the problem I can make it an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- You cannot select the `Other` [optgroup element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp), try it manual, doesnt work, might give an exception when you try.
- [`element.select_by_value()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=select#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) method will select the element, it does not return an element to click on, so you cant click on it. It will change the select for you.

The code should look like this instead:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('userDomain'))
select.select_by_value('261')
```